# GCP policy to enforce to use EKM (externally managed key) in KMS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

Anyone knows how can we enforce the use of EKM (externally managed key) in the GCP KMS?
I would like to avoid using Google-generated keys in the KMS as per our company policy.

Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check

Comment: Is your issue resolved ? If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution or can you accept or upvote if the existing answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

External key manager (EKM) is the key manager used outside of Google Cloud to manage your keys. You can create and manage external keys either [via the internet](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/ekm-internet) or [via a Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/ekm-virtual-private-cloud).  The key resides on the external system, and is never sent to Google.

You can store external keys in the following external key management partner systems:
Supported today:
Fortanix
Futurex
Thales
Virtru

With Cloud EKM, you can use keys that you manage within a [supported external key management partner](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/ekm#supported_partners) to protect data within Google Cloud. You can protect data at rest in [supported CMEK integration services](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/ekm#supported_services), or by calling the Cloud Key Management Service API directly.

**For more information on EKM refer to the documentation** **[google-kms-ekm](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/ekm).**

**EDIT-1**

Below procedure to [implement EKM](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/ekm#how_it_works):

1. First, you need to create or use an existing key in a [supported external key management partner system](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/ekm#supported_partners). This key has a unique URI or key path.
2. Next, you can grant your Google Cloud project access to use the key, in the external key management partner system.
3. In your Google Cloud project, you create a Cloud EKM key, using the URI or key path for the externally-managed key.

You can also follow the step-by-step instructions to [create a Cloud EKM key accessed via the internet](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/ekm-internet#create_ekm_key) or [create a Cloud EKM key accessed via a VPC](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/ekm-virtual-private-cloud#create_ekm_key)

**EKM while creating VM**:

Console -> Compute Engine -> VM Instances -> Create Instance -> Boot disk -> CHANGE -> SHOW ADVANCED CONFIGURATION -> Encryption -> choose the encryption management solution you want to use for the disk.

**EKM while creating storage bucket:**

Console -> Cloud Storage -> Create Bucket -> Choose how to protect object data -> Enable “customer managed encryption key”
By default “Google-managed key” Encryption type will be used.
The Cloud Console cannot be used to upload an object with a customer-supplied encryption key. Use gsutil or the client libraries instead.

For more information refer to the documentation [cloud storage customer supplied encryption keys](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/using-customer-supplied-keys#console).

**EDIT -2**

Currently it is impossible to enforce EKM as an [organization policy constraint.](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints)

There is a Feature Request on this similar requirement where the product team is working . You can track the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/198264580) .

As a temporary workaround  you can create a log-based alert or metric and filter the audit log with "kmsKeyName" keyword or exclude the keyword for non CMEK logs.

protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail="SA to filter"
protoPayload.@type="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
"kmsKeyName".

Note that the query can be modified based on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how can we enforce uses to use it for encryption when a storage bucket or a compute engine VM is created?

Comment: You can enforce using [cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption) or [compute engine VM creation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-managed-encryption) depending on your use case.

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: I have updated answer, Please check

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Actually, I know how to use the EKM, but I want to have a method to force uses can "only" use EKM while users create storage bucket or VM instance. How can I do it?

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check